# Mersenne numbers fail primality test at 2047 itself. How could we believe Mersennes are primes?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, math-history

M$_{11}=2047$ is a composite number.    How could one, not check the primaility of such a small number and believe that all Mersenne numbers are primes?

Comment: It baffles me as well, but the question really is who conjectured this?

Comment: Certainly not Mersenne...he was perfectly aware that there were composite Mersenne numbers see, e.g., [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_conjectures)

Comment: I've never heard of this conjecture...

Comment: More so, the conjecture of infinitely many Mersenne primes remains unsolved.

Comment: It would improve your Question to cite a source for the claim you are asking about.  It seems possible a misunderstanding has crept in, confusing e.g. Mersenne numbers vs Fermat numbers.

Comment: It's worth browsing Dickson's History of the Theory of Numbers someday, because mathematicians in ancient times and through the dark ages sometimes stated as known fact results that were pure conjecture.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think anybody ever thought all Mersenne numbers are prime.

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime):

> Mersenne primes take their name from the 17th-century French scholar Marin Mersenne, who compiled what was supposed to be a list of Mersenne primes with exponents up to 257, as follows:
>
> $$2, 3, 5, 7, 13, 17, 19, 31, 67, 127, 257$$
>
> His list was completely accurate until 31, but then becomes largely incorrect, as Mersenne mistakenly included $M_{67}$ and $M_{257}$ (which are composite), and omitted $M_{61}$, $M_{89}$, and $M_{107}$ (which are prime). Mersenne gave little indication how he came up with his list

You may be confusing Mersenne numbers with the *Fermat numbers*, $2^{2^n}+1$. These were conjectured by Fermat to be prime, but Euler found that $2^{2^5}+1$ is composite.

Comment: I stand corrected.  I thought like Fermat, Mersenne also thought that the formula generates primes only.  When I see back, I realize I have misunderstood - it was never told that there was conjecture like that.  Though I know that Mersenne numbers have some properties, do they deserve a special name and special study?

Comment: @user3141822: My understanding is that there are more efficient specialized primality testing algorithms known for Mersenne numbers than for random numbers of the same size, which is why the largest known prime has often been a Mersenne prime. Apart from the (essentially pointless) search for large primes, I don't know that Mersenne primes are considered to be of any special importance in number theory.